how to display flex 2 diffrent components in admin panel
i'm makin admin panel using MERN stack but my bootstraps library not working properly even i installed everything right. how could i resolved .I tried it using bootstrap and also css properties but both are not working ..i want to add my data in front of a sidebar but it goes to under the sidebar

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
